# Do I need to quarantine in Poland when I have a negative test after arriving from outside the Schengen area?

Tags: covid-19, poland, quarantine

I have a question regarding required quarantine in Poland. There are two websites I do not get which one is correct?

https://www.gov.pl/web/coronavirus/travel

Stated that Since 23 January, persons holding a negative result of a test for SARS-CoV-2 are exempt from the obligation to undergo quarantine. The test must be conducted before crossing the border and is valid for 48 hours from the moment of receiving the result.

https://www.gov.pl/web/gsse-warszawa/od-30-marca-nowe-zasady-dotyczace-kwarantanny-dla-przyjezdzajacych-do-polski

Stated that  On the other hand, those arriving from outside the Schengen area will be sent to quarantine without exception, regardless of the test they have. Vaccinated people will be released from quarantine. The new rules will apply from Tuesday, March 30.

And the border police (last sentence)

https://www.strazgraniczna.pl/pl/aktualnosci/8884,Koronawirus-wjazd-do-Polski.html

The latest update which I did not understand is number 30:

https://www.strazgraniczna.pl/pl/cudzoziemcy/covid-epidemia-koronawi/8578,Outbreak-of-coronavirus-rules-of-entry-and-stay-on-the-territory-of-the-Republic.html

Comment: nobody?.........

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.